# i can not access the post in custom template of my wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, php

i added following code to use custom template for my recipes single page

```
function override_single_template( $single_template ){
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == "recipes"){
        $single_template  = plugins_url('/recipe-single-page-template.php',__FILE__);
    }
    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'override_single_template',10);
```

and in my template i added following code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: recipe-single-page-template
Template Post Type: recipes
*/
require_once("../../../wp-load.php");
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php echo $post->ID?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

but i do not access the post and echo out post id will cuses the following error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

var dump $post outputs null

```
NULL
```

and following code will print out my custom template address

```
$current_url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $current_url;
```

top code result:

```
https://charter.test/wp-content/plugins/recipe-plugin/templates/single-recipes.php
```

now whate should i do?

Comment: `plugins_url()` returns an URL, so you should use [`plugin_dir_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) instead. And why do you load `wp-load.php` in the template?

Comment: because i dont access wordpress built in functions without it

Comment: WordPress functions are always available from within PHP templates so long as they're loaded properly. But your filter callback is returning an URL when it should be a filesystem path, e.g. `/home/user/var/www/wordpress/file.php`. So you need to correct that and no need to load `wp-load.php` from the template.

Comment: thanks.that works great